# Does being prone affect your Combat Maneuver Defense (CMD)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prone

When a character is prone, is their CMD penalized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  [Penalties to your AC affect your CMD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Combat-Maneuver-Defense):

> Any penalties to a creature's AC also apply to its CMD.

and [you have an AC penalty (to melee attacks at least) when prone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Prone).

> A prone defender gains a +4 bonus to Armor Class against ranged attacks, but takes a –4 penalty to AC against melee attacks.

Comment: I don't know what that link said before, but it no longer says anything that implies what you're answering.  If you see this comment before I find the answer, can you find where it still says it?

Comment: I'm not clear what the confusion is but I put the exact quotes from those links into the answer.

Comment: Oh weird, I read through that at least three times and didn't see it.  But you're right, it's definitely there.